# Downloading all jupyter notebooks from Coursera [tar size exeeding 100MB]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

As mentioned in the [coursera help articles](https://learner.coursera.help/hc/en-us/articles/360004990332-Download-Jupyter-Workspace-files) in order to download notebooks from the class we need to zip all the content of root folder into single file and download the final workspace.tar.gz using these steps: but it is not working all courses.
Anyone knows proper way to do this !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Open the home folder of your coursera jupyter notebook:**
  you can do this by opening any of the course notebooks and thanm selecting `file> open` **or** by clicking on `Jupyter icon` at the top left corner of notebook.
- **Open terminal inside the notebook:**
  On the home page of your notebooks, at the top left corner select `new> terminal`
- **Check in which dir you are:**
  this is important as different courses have their materials in different dir!  
  Some courses have a dir name `jovyan` and inside that you have two folders generally `work` and `work-ro`.
  in **work** you have your actual content that you can see on your notebook home page.
  in **work-ro** you have only `read_only` folder. This same folder you have it in your `work` dir but you cant open the content of that folder after downloading!                     (I dont know why I cant open it)
  **I turns out that this folder contains images which are in your notebooks. that is the reason you will have to zip both these folders.**

  Its not necessary that all the course have this folder named `work`!
  In some courses materials are directly inside `root` dir. In such cases you can find the directory with your material by finding folder name ending with **-ro**
  **Ex** in one of my course I located a folder named `TF-ro` and there was another folder named `TF` containing all course material! As per above pattern `TF-ro` contained **read_only** folder.

  **Just in case you are wondering how to navigate inside terminal: [Use these commands]**
  **ls:** list everything inside the folder
  **cd:** to change the folder you are currently in
  **Ex:** `cd .. #go to previous folder` `cd <dirname> #go to that specified folder`
- **compress both the folders using tar:**
  Navigate to the folder which contains both of these folders i.e `work` and `work-ro` or if you read my second case than `Tf` and `TF-ro` or folders in your case.

  **Use this to make tar file:**
  Use this when your folder contains only two dirs that you want
  `tar -czvf <choose a name>.tar.gz <address of dir to compress>`
  **Ex:** `tar -czvf data.tar.gz ./`
  use this when you are in root folder and you have multiple dir along with the folders you want
  `tar -czvf <choose a name>.tar.gz <dir1 addres> <dir2 addres>`
  **Ex:** `tar -czvf data.tar.gz ./work ./work-ro`

  **Just in case you are wondering!**
  **./** means current folder.
- **Check the size of your tar file:**
  This is also important!!
  If your process of making tar file is taking too long **or** your terminal appears to be frozen ! than there are some big files in your home folder.
  You can check the size of your tar file using: `ls -lh data.tar.gz`.
  **Normally the size should not be more than 10 - 15 Mbs.**
  If your size is in GBs than you are mostly downloading large amount of datasets and csv files!
  you cannot download big files like this!
  **[Workaround for this problem are mentioned below]**
  run this command: `du`
  This will list all the dir's and the size of dir's in current folder.
  Figure out which folder has more size.
  **Note:** size shown in this commands are in **Number of sections occupied** `1 section = 1024 bytes`
  Exclude these folder wile making tar...

  In order to remove previous tar file run `rm data.tar.gz`
  make the tar like this:
  `tar -czvf <yourName>.tar.gz --exclude=<address to exclude> <dir/dirs to zip>`
  **Ex:** `tar -czvf data.tar.gz --exclude=./work/data --exclude=./work/- ./work ./work-ro`
- **Move the file :**
  You can only see the content in the work folder (or any other folder your content is in) on your class's notebook home folder.
  This is why we will move over tar file to that folder.
  move using this command `mv <file name> <location>` **Ex :**`mv data.tar.gz ./work`
- **Download your file:**
  Now you can see your file in your home folder in your browser. simply select the file you will see download option available at the top !!
  **Sometimes you dont see the download button on the top, in such cases...**
  `right click your file> save link As> then save it with .tar.gz extension`
  Just to confirm check the size of file you have downloaded and one in your classroom!!

  **Work Around for downloading big data sets:**
  Your course generally does not use all the csv's or data sets that it has stored in the data folder. When you do the assignments see which files are / data sets are used and download only those manually.  `i.e opening that file on your classroom and downloading it using using file> download`

  if you still want the entire thing than make separate tar file of that folder only. Than split the tar file (you will find it online easily) and than download as I have mentioned earlier!
  After the download it is necessary to concatenate the files:

  `cat allfiles.tar.gz.part.* > allfiles.tar.gz`

  **I would suggest not to waste time in doing this!!** Just download what is required and that's it!!

  I hope this was helpful !! cauz I spent 5 hr figuring out how to do it !! ENJOY !!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could initialize a git repo and push it to your GitHub account.

1. Open terminal (Jupiter home > new > terminal)
2. Run the following code: (I'm assuming you've already created a GitHub repo, if not create one and then do the following; you'll need the link to your repo)

   ```
     git init

     git config --global user.name "test"

     git config --global user.email "test"

     git add -A; git commit -m "commit"

     git remote add origin <_your-github-repo-url_>

     git push origin master -u --verbose
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can just compress all the programming exercise (notebook + data) by placing this commands at the beginning of your notebook:

```
import os

!tar chvfz notebook.tar.gz *
print("File size: " + str(os.path.getsize("notebook.tar.gz")/1e6) + " MB")
if os.path.getsize("notebook.tar.gz")/1e6 >100 :
    print("Splitting file")
    !split -b 100M notebook.tar.gz "notebook.tar.gz."
```